# How to select query as XML format?

Tags: asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008

My query selects fields in xml. What I need is to display the xml not in one line as

```
<AllPlayers><Player><fbid>1236598</fbid><fbname>joan</fbname><fbscore>99999999</fbscore></Player><Player><fbid>55559999888</fbid><fbname>smith</fbname><fbscore>99999999</fbscore></Player></AllPlayers>
```

but as :

```
<AllPlayers>
  <Player>
    <fbid>1236598</fbid>
    <fbname>Mohamed Hamam</fbname>
    <fbscore>99999999</fbscore>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <fbid>55559999888</fbid>
    <fbname>mostafaa Hamam</fbname>
    <fbscore>99999999</fbscore>
  </Player>
</AllPlayers>
```

my query:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procGetPlayerScore]
AS BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (10)
        fbid ,   
        Name as fbname,
        Score  as fbscore        
    FROM 
        dbo.FB_Player
    ORDER BY 
        Score DESC 
    FOR XML  PATH('Player'), ROOT('AllPlayers')
END
```

asp page:

```cs
Response.Expires = -1;
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

using(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["x"].ConnectionString))
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "procGetPlayerScore";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    c.Open();
    System.Xml.XmlReader r = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
    string playersXml = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    xmlc.InnerText = playersXml;
    System.Xml.XmlTextWriter w = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Response.Output);

    c.Close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to display this XML in asp.net? or just want to have "pretty print" in SQL management studio

Comment: in asp.net i edited my question

Comment: how you print result in ASP.NET?

Comment: i edited my question y can check now

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `Formatting` in `XmlTextWriter` like bellow:
(I assume that `xmlc` is `XmlDocument`)

```
[your code]
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter w = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Response.Output);
w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlc.WriteContentTo(w);
c.Close();
}
```

**Update**

Below updated code based on comments:

```
[your code]
string playersXml = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
System.Xml.XmlTextWriter w = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Response.Output);
w.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
 using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
 {
   xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
   xmlTextWriter.Flush();
   playersXml  = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
 }

xmlc.InnerText = playersXml;
c.Close();
}
```

Comment: xmlc is div as container for xml

Comment: Why you put xml into div container? Especially when output type is xml

Comment: as i will send this page to flash game

Comment: i had this error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: I made mistakein `doc.LoadXml(xml);` should be playersXml instead of xml

Comment: it worked but with different formatting from xml file please find the attached image that i added for question

Comment: Firefox have always problems with formatting, try to check source code of the web page